# Order rows by amount of columns in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently outputting all of my members by adding the MySQL clause `ORDER BY id DESC`, but I feel that doesn't reward people that are active on my service.

I thought about judging the order by the **amount of entries in another table** they have under their ID.

Essentially, I'm asking if it's possible to **order columns in a MAIN table counting the amount of rows where the users ID is in the column of the row**.

Something pseudo to this

```
SELECT user_id,name,etc FROM users ORDER BY ( 
  COUNT(SELECT FROM users_interactions WHERE user_id = user_id) ******* 
) ASC
```

In the end of the **COUNT** statement, the `user_id = user_id` was just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there - what you need to do is to put `COUNT` inside `SELECT`:

```
SELECT user_id,name,etc FROM users u ORDER BY ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM users_interactions i
    WHERE i.user_id = u.user_id
) ASC
```

You could also do it using a `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.etc
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_interactions i ON i.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name, u.etc
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated. I also loved how you started with **You are almost there**, felt like my mother teaching me how to ride a bike. :P